# Macro e VBA que apague os registros mais antigos, se forem o mesmo valor

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data, validação, macro

Fala galera, sou novo aqui e estou desesperado por uma ajuda.

Preciso que apague os registros mais antigos de uma lista de várias viagens, mantendo apenas o mais recente deles. O print abaixo deixa mais claro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso eu precisaria que os do dia 21/09 e 23/09 fossem apagados, restando apenas os do dia 26/09.
O problema é que tem repetições nas placas e que, se forem do mais recentes, precisam ser mantidas.

Ajudem um universitário desesperadoooo :(

Comment: Leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas) e leia também [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta?cb=1)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, irei reformular mais tardar

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub removerAntigo()

Dim UltimaLinha As Long
UltimaLinha = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To UltimaLinha

If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Exit Sub

If Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i + 1, 3) Then

    If Cells(i, 1) <= Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
    
    Rows(i).Delete
    If i = 2 Then i = 1
    
    End If

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Eu acabei fazendo um escopo aqui mas ainda não tive sucesso, minha macro exclui valores, mas não mantem as placas iguais com a mesma data, como mostra na imagem da pergunta. Também, não se resume a uma placa apenas, esta foi um exemplo, não me atentei em falar isto antes . Resumindo: vou colar um relatório de determinado intervalo de datas (1 semana por exemplo) e quero me certificar de que não terei duplicidade no momento que eu usá-lo para analisar os dados. Sendo um relatório de transporte, em que posso ter mais de um conhecimento por placa (como é o caso do dia 26/09 na imagem), e diferentes placas no relatório, sempre mantendo os mais recentes.